# Quasiconvexity of the composition of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Consider $A: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n \times n} $ and $B \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n \times m}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$.

Assume that, for all $y \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$, the function $x \mapsto c^\top A(x) \, y$ is convex.

I am wondering if the function $x \mapsto c^\top A(x) B x$ is [quasiconvex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function). 
If not, find under what additional condition would it be quasiconvex.

Comment: I tried to apply the fact that the composition of a quasiconvex function and a non-decreasing one preserves quasiconvexity, but the order seems reversed.

Comment: I'm curious if you have a particular $A(x)$ in mind. I frankly can't even conceive of a case where your premise would hold; i.e., where $c^TA(x)y$ is convex for all $y$. Of course, it could be true if $A(x)$ is linear, but you said convex, so I'm assuming at least some nonlinearity.

Comment: Yes, please assume some (convex) nonlinearity. One example is $A(x) := \text{Diag}\left( e^{x_1}, \ldots, e^{ x_n } \right)$. Let me restrict to non-negative reals for simplicity.